# cakePHP WHERE IN CLAUSE : Array to String convertion

Tags: cakephp, where-in

Hello I want to get all the data from a table that are in the range of those arrays below :
//A data sent from AJAX to PHP

```
$authors = $_POST['authors'];
$articles= $_POST['articles'];
```

The following cakePHP query is giving me the following errors :

Query:

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Mymodel.name' => array($authors ,$articles)),'order'=>'Mymodel.id DESC'));
```

Error:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 2591]
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 1: ...Mymodel" WHERE "Mymodel"."name" IN (Array, Array) ... ^
```

What am I doing wrong? I know that if I had an arry as `$authors = array('sss','rrr');` it will work so why it does not in my case?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `$authors` and `$articles` variables are arrays already.

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
      'Mymodel.name' => array_merge($authors, $articles)
   ),
  'order'=>'Mymodel.id DESC')
);
```

Comment: There's a fault in your code, the `OR` array cannot have the same key twice, so the conditions should be wrapped in arrays as well - `array('OR' => array(array('Mymodel.name' => $authors), array('Mymodel.name' => $articles)))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I want, I don't want an 'OR' clause, I want something like this : $article=array('Jhon','Bill'); $autors = array('article2','article3');                                                                   $this->Mymodel->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Mymodel.name' => array("Jhon","Bill","article2","article3")),'order'=>'Mymodel.id DESC')); This last query will work but this one will not : $this->Mymodel->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Mymodel.name'=>array($articles,$autors)),'order'=>'Mymodel.id DESC')); so how can I make it working?

Comment: hahaha, were you drinking or what? Now we both are on the same page and smashing it worked as I wanted, Thanks a lot :)